# Can you throw an exception from a Raw AspectJ Before advice

Tags: exception, aop, aspectj

I'm writing a non-spring aop aspect using aspectJ and I'm writing a before advice for it.

In my before advice, let's say I want to open a file.  So I execute it as such:

```
 public before(): mypointcut() {
    File file = new File("myfile");
    file.getCanonicalPath();
 }
```

But IntelliJ gripes about IOException being an unhandled exception.  How can I write the before advice such that it can either catch and rethrow the exception or allow the unhandled exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to hand the exception up the call stack you must add a throws declaration to your advice just like with a normal method call:

```
public before() throws IOException: mypointcut() {...}
```

This advice can only be applied on methods that declare throwing this exception (or a parent of the exception) themselves.

In order to rethrow it you need to catch the exception and rethrow it in an instance of RuntimeException like so:

```
public before(): mypointcut() {
    File file = new File("myfile");
    try {
        file.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If this is a good idea is a another story...

Comment: I see where my confusion was.  I only recently read (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) that Advices can only throw certain kinds of exceptions: Runtime being one of them.  So you're correct, if I get an exception, I need to wrap it in an "advice throwable" exception.